# All LineItems as array for single and multiple lineitems in xml to json conversion

Tags: arrays, json, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

we are trying to add the square/array [ for each and every lineitems of "Address" in xml to json conversion.
The lineitems could be 1 or more but it should be embeded in Square bracket "Address": [[{...}], [{...}]].

xml file can contain atleast 1 Address or morethan 50 lineitems

xml file:

```
<root>
    <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
    <LastName>Fin</LastName>
    <Details>
        <Id_Number>111</Id_Number>
        <Location>NC</Location>
        <Contact>
             <PhoneNumber>+1 323</PhoneNumber>
         </Contact>
    </Details>
    <Details>
        <Id_Number>222</Id_Number>
        <Location>TX</Location>
        <Contact>
             <PhoneNumber>+1 323</PhoneNumber>
         </Contact>
    </Details>
    <Address>
        <Locality>Urban</Locality>
        <Type>Mobile</Type>
     </Address>
     <Address>
        <Locality>Rural</Locality>
        <Type>Landline</Type>
     </Address>
</root>
```

Expected jsonfile:

```
{
    "FirstName": "Alex",
    "LastName": "Fin",
    "Details": [ [
      {
        "Id_Number": 111,
        "Location": "NC",
        "Contact": {
          "PhoneNumber": "+1 323"
        }
      },
      {
        "Id_Number": 222,
        "Location": "TX",
        "Contact": {
          "PhoneNumber": "+1 323"
        }
      }
    ]],
    "Address": [
      [
       {
        "Locality": "Urban"
        "Type": "Mobile"
      }
      ],
      [
       {
        "Locality": "Rural"
        "Type": "Landline"
      }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

xsltCode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[(*) and . castable as xs:double]">
    <number key="{local-name()}">{.}</number>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:boolean" select="false()"/>
    <map>
      <xsl:if test="$key">
        <xsl:attribute name="key" select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-group()[2] or self::Details or self::Address">
                  <array key="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="self::Details">
                        <array>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                          </xsl:apply-templates>                        
                        </array>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                          <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                      </xsl:otherwise>                      
                    </xsl:choose>
                  </array>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

A further twist of the code with

```
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:boolean" select="false()"/>
    <map>
      <xsl:if test="$key">
        <xsl:attribute name="key" select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-group()[2] or self::Details or self::Address">
                  <array key="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="self::Details">
                        <array>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                          </xsl:apply-templates>                        
                        </array>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:when test="self::Address">
                        <xsl:iterate select="current-group()">
                          <array>
                            <map>
                              <xsl:apply-templates>
                                <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                              </xsl:apply-templates>
                            </map>
                          </array>
                        </xsl:iterate>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                          <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                      </xsl:otherwise>                      
                    </xsl:choose>
                  </array>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>
```

might make the test case work I think but I guess you will come back with a slightly different input sample and ask for another twist.

Comment: H ..Thank you...its not a twist..similar with different scenarios...the input file updated with 'Distance' & 'Miles' child element. But its not populating in the json file.<xsl:when test="self::Address/Distance"> Tried with the xsl template <Address>
            <Locality>Urban</Locality>
            <Distance>
               <Miles>2</Miles>
            </Distance>
             <Type>Mobile</Type>
         </Address>

Comment: <xsl:when test="self::Address/Distance/*"> is providing only the values in Distance elements not the entire segment..without child elements like 'Distance' am getting [][] for each and every lineitem...in general all the data should be populate under the lineitem including the child elements

Comment: Thanks much for the support...I modified the code...its working for single or multiple lineitems & Child elements....</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="self::Address">
                        <xsl:iterate select="current-group()">
<array>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="self::Address">

                          </xsl:apply-templates>                        
                        </array>
                        </xsl:iterate>
                      </xsl:when>